# OpenGL ModelView Matrix and Projection Matrix

Tags: opengl-es, three.js

I am working in THREE.js 65. I want to know what is in the following code

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(newP.m);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

in openGL. I want to apply the following code in three.js. In the code newP is a 4x4 Matrix.

Comment: Could you please reformulate your question. It's unclear what you're actually want to know.

Comment: I am working in THREE.js 65. I want to know what is in the following code glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);glLoadMatrixf(newP.m);glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); in openGL` I want to use the above code in three.js format. Please any one help to understand the openGL code and to apply in three.js format.

Answer (score 0):

This code sets the camera projection matrix with the first two lines and then switches mode to set or create the modelview matrix. These matrices should not really be changed directly in three.js but can be accessed as `camera.projectionMatrix.elements[]`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The third line you said set or create the ModelViewMatrix. How to calculate and set matrix value to modelview matrix or create the modelview matrix in three.js

Comment: OpenGL is a state machine. So the code turns on the flag for the modelview matrix and the code that follows creates it or sets it, I dont know (you do not provide it).